# iphone writeTofile error

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

im getting a "CFDictionaryAddValue(): immutable collection 0xd5aea0 given to mutating function"

error when i try to write a string to a file using the follwowing code

```
NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithString:xmlData];
NSError *error = nil;
if ([xmlString writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error])
```

xmlData was a mutable string but xmlString is not.

any ideas?

Comment: You sure it is this code generating the error?  I can't see anything wrong with it (at first glance).

Comment: does this work? NSString *xmlString = [xmlData copy]; ...your other code here, then... [xmlString release];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me in cocoa.

```
NSString * xmlData = @"This is some random string";
NSString * xmlString = [NSString stringWithString:xmlData];
NSError * error = nil;
if (![xmlString writeToFile:@"data.txt"
                 atomically:NO
                   encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                      error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"writeToFile failed: %@", error);
}
```

I would check:

- How do you get xmlData? Is it a NSString?
- Do you specify file path within your app bundle? You will not be able to write outside your application directory apart from Documents (?) I think.

This is how you would specify file in Documents directory:

```
// Documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// <Application Home>/Documents/foo.plist
NSString *fooPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@“foo.plist”];
```